# Can Python's strptime handle Python's logging time format?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

By default, Python's `logging` module uses a special format for times, which includes milliseconds: `2003-01-23 00:29:50,411`.

Notably, `strftime` and `strptime` don't have a standard "milliseconds" specifier (so `logging` first prints everything else with `strftime` and then inserts the milliseconds separately). This means there's no obvious way to parse these strings using the standard library.

However, everything *seems* to work fine when I use `strptime` with the `%f` (microseconds) specifier: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f`. While `%f` in `strftime` prints a six-digit number, in `strptime` it's apparently happy to take a three-digit number instead, and assume the last three digits are zeroes.

My question is—**is this standard/documented behavior**? Can I rely on this to keep working, or is it liable to break unexpectedly in new versions? I haven't been able to find anything about this in the Python docs (or `man strptime`, which doesn't even mention `%f`), but this seems like a common enough use case that I'd be surprised if nobody's needed it before.

I could also append three zeroes to the time string before passing it to `strptime`, but that's hacky enough that I'd prefer not to do it unless necessary.

Comment: And yes, `411000` microseconds is the same as [`411` milliseconds](https://www.google.com/search?q=411+milliseconds+to+microseconds&oq=411+milliseconds+to+microseconds&aqs=chrome..69i57.9701j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @accdias Yep, what's what I'm currently doing (using `%f`). My question is whether that's standard/documented behavior or if a future update might break it unexpectedly.

Comment: @FObersteiner Oddly enough, despite that note, `%f` is not a C-standard one as far as I can tell, which is why it's not listed in (my) `man strptime`. From the Python docs: "`%f` is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available)."

Comment: @Draconis, yep... Note 5 from the [Technical Details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) explains it.

Comment: right, `%f` is not C-standard... `C` still keeps surprising me.

Comment: I don't know who or why my comment about it was removed, but I still think `datetime.fromisoformat()` and `datetime.isoformat()` are the best way to handle those strings.

Comment: @accdias Rather looks like answering, violating the comment instructions.

Comment: @KellyBundy, sounds reasonable. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @accdias Btw while the question asks about strptime, it is about logging output, and the [logging source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/logging/__init__.py) mentions ISO8601, really making that appropriate as an answer in my opinion (if it works ... I didn't check myself).

Comment: @KellyBundy, you are right. I just did that. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact standard—for Python, at least. (`%f` is not a C-standard directive, which is why I couldn't find it in `man strptime`.) It's in the notes under [Technical Detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail):

> When used with the `strptime()` method, the `%f` directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right. `%f` is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available).

Thanks to Kelly Bundy for pointing me to this in the comments!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comments, I think the best (and safest) way to handle such strings is by using [`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and [`datetime.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). This way, you don't have to care about messing with format templates ever:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2003-01-23 00:29:50,411')
datetime.datetime(2003, 1, 23, 0, 29, 50, 411000)
>>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me: `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2022-11-15 06:03:10,931'`

Comment: @Draconis, what Python version are you using? As describe in the documentation: _"New in version 3.7"_.

Comment: I'm running Python 3.11.0, BTW.

Comment: I'm on version 3.8.10. It looks like `fromisoformat` got more lenient in what it accepted in 3.11.

Comment: I guess so. One thing you can try is `datetime.fromisoformat('2022-11-15 06:03:10,931'.replace(',', '.'))`.